# acceder a una variable desde otra función en golang

Tags: go

tengo el siguiente código:

```
func AbrirConexionBd() {
    db, err := sql.Open("mssql", "server=127.0.0.1;user id=sa;password=...")
    Debug(err)
    _ = db
}

func CerrarConexionBd() {
    AbrirConexionBd()
    defer db.Close()

}
```

como accede la funcion CerrarConexionBd a la variable db ¿? para cerrar la conexion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Una solución es devolver la conexión en la función `AbrirConexionDb()`:

```
func AbrirConexionBd() *sql.DB {
    db, err := sql.Open("mssql", "server=127.0.0.1;user id=sa;password=...")
    Debug(err)
    _ = db
   return db
}

func CerrarConexionBd() {
    db := AbrirConexionBd()
    defer db.Close()

}
```

Otra solución seria crear un Singleton y retornar la conexión (recomendada):

```
var (
    db   *sqlx.DB
    once sync.Once
)
func createConnection() *sql.DB {
    once.Do(func() {
       db, err := sql.Open("mssql", "server=127.0.0.1;user id=sa;password=...")
       Debug(err)
    })
    return db
}

func CerrarConexionBd() {
    conn := AbrirConexionBd()
    defer conn.Close()
}
```

NOTA: entiendo que el control de errores lo tienes implementado.

Espero que estas soluciones puedan ayudarte a solucionar el problema.

Un saludo

Answer (score 0):

Se puede usar una variable global, en este caso para manejar el pool de conexión.

```
var (
    db  *sql.DB
    err error
)

func AbrirConexionBd() {
    db, err = sql.Open("mssql", "server=127.0.0.1;user id=sa;password=...")
    Debug(err)
}

func CerrarConexionBd() {
    db.Close()
}
```